# android can't execute permission denied from the folder

Tags: android

/data/local/tmp/minicap-devel /data/local/tmp/minicap-devel/minicap -P x@x/0
/system/bin/sh: /data/local/tmp/minicap-devel/minicap: can't execute: Permission denied

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: i need to access file from this folder in android /system/bin/

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: what's the device you are using?